# Configuration/Plugin to format java code in gitlab

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I am using gitlab to commit/synchronize my java code. I am my standard xml file to format maven java code. I have configured pre-commit hook which works perfectly ok. It formats the code and push it into github. But problem is, this pre-commit hook must be present in every other individual. I want to configure format plugin in my gitlab workspace, so that whomsoever push, the code will get formatted they don't have configured pre-commit hook. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for
[Custom server-side Git hooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/custom_hooks.html).

A GitLab server administrator can add such a script file under the project’s
repository directory in a new directory called `custom_hooks`.

See the above link for details.

Comment: What will be my approach to format java code

Comment: In my maven project's pom.xml i have specified formatter-maven-plugin so i custom_hooks will be executing mvn commands?

Comment: You might be referring to [GitLab Maven Repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/packages/maven_repository.html), but I don't have experience with that.